# Do DS cartridge batteries run dry?

Tags: nintendo-ds, physical-media

Do Nintendo DS cartridge batteries (do those games have batteries?) run dry after some time like GBA/GBC/GB games? Is it true that they will last at least 100 years or something?

Comment: Nope. Nintendo invented Infinite Energy Battery Technology™, but then patented it to ensure that it could only ever be used for video game cartridges.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A DS cartridge is like a micro SD card, so they don't have any battery inside.

And regarding *life expectancy of an SD* card I'll quote [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/17350):

> Flash memory indeed has limited write cycles. However, by now it is unlikely that you'll encounter this within the normal lifetime of such a card. **Usually this is in the order of 100,000 write cycles** today and SD cards include circuitry to manage wear-leveling, that is, spread out writes over the storage media evenly to avoid "hot spots"—pages that are written too frequently and therefore failing early.

As most games save less than once or twice per ten minutes, I'd say that the electronics in a cartridge will go bad before you cannot save anymore. You will not be able to exhaust its write cycles. So, it should work for at least 40 or 50 years.

Comment: Thanks!
So like how much years can last a DS game without its save file being erased?

Comment: @Beavoru I've edited the answer.

Comment: @pinckerman For someone who can't interpret how many write cycles will occur in regular gameplay (in other words, for the layman gamer who isn't necessarily that well-versed in software storage) an approximation of how many times the DS card will use  a "write cycle" would help to put a sense of scale on "**100,000 write cycles**"

Comment: It's more complicated because, while a DS game is very much like an SD card, it isn't the exact same thing. It contains different technology to manage wear that we aren't privy to.

However in terms of a write cycle, that would be one save of your game. So playing for a few hours and then saving would incur 1 write cycle. Saving every 5 minutes would incur 12 write cycles in an hour.

Comment: Thanks, so it's about the use, but not the time used, unlike the old cartridge games.

Comment: @Beavoru. Keep in mind that your save files ***will not*** simply vanish when you reach the write cycling limit. You will still be able to load your previous game, but you won't be able to save any more.

Comment: This takes me down memory lane, the several NES cartridges that implemented battery storage so as to abolish the insanity of metroid codes. I guess it wasn't insane at the time, it was just the way it was and you lived with it.

Comment: @MrBoJangles Have you ever played International Superstar Soccer Deluxe on NES? Pure insanity.

Comment: @pinckerman I have not, but after a few minutes here, it looks like an invitation to epilepsy: http://www.letsplaysnes.com/play-international-superstar-soccer-deluxe-online/?play=true#content. Do you recommend this?

Comment: @MrBoJangles That was my first soccer game. *Scenario* mode was a cool feature. But those 60-character save codes were a bit awkward :)

Comment: @pinckerman oy, that's unkind to make people use those codes. That must have been before the publisher had user experience people.

Comment: I was a developer on one of the launch-window DS titles (Sprung). At least at the time, Nintendo used ordinary flash NVRAM and there was no wear-leveling in the cartridges (and only a tiny amount of flash); developers were required to only save when prompted or between levels, specifically to avoid running out of write cycles. Later cartridges may have changed this, however. And of course 3DS just stores your save files on your system's SD card - no flash on the cartridge itself.

Comment: @Nolonar "You will still be able to load your previous game, but you won't be able to save any more" - is that true, or will it load once, try to save, and permanently corrupt/erase the file? Is the DS flash architecture fail-safe?

Comment: @Nolonar The existing data must be deleted before new data can be written.  This means you will be able to load your old files, but if you try to save over them then you will lose both the old (overwritten) and new (corrupted) files.

Comment: @MrBoJangles uuh no, it's not out of unkindness (that's a word now, deal with it) nor lack of user experience. It's that the alternative was not having saves. The technology for save games wasn't there at an affordable price